# How to Add data inside an array in mongodb Spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I want to add data in `prices` json array. It already has one object and whenever I run the same block of code again I want to add the next data in `prices` array.

```
{
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "prices": [
        {
            "date": "2018-09-22 18:32:08",
            "price": "256.00"
        }//add another data here when I run the same block of code again as another object
    ]
}
```

The POJOs are like this,
`PastPrice.java`

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "symbol",
    "prices"
})
public class PastPrice {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("symbol")
    private String symbol;
    @JsonProperty("prices")
    private List<Price> prices = null;

    @JsonProperty("symbol")
    public String getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    @JsonProperty("symbol")
    public void setSymbol(String symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    @JsonProperty("prices")
    public List<Price> getPrices() {
        return prices;
    }

    @JsonProperty("prices")
    public void setPrices(List<Price> prices) {
        this.prices = prices;
    }

}
```

Then, `Price.java`

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "date",
    "price"
})
public class Price {
    @Id
    @JsonProperty("date")
    private String date;
    @JsonProperty("price")
    private String price;

    @JsonProperty("date")
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @JsonProperty("date")
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @JsonProperty("price")
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    @JsonProperty("price")
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

I am saving the data like this in the controller

```
@GetMapping("/save")
public void getAndSaveStocks() {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        StockData stockData = restTemplate.getForObject(Constants.API,
                StockData.class);
        List<Company> sl = stockData.getCompanies();   

        PastPrice pastPrice = new PastPrice();
for (Company company : sl) {


                    pastPrice = new PastPrice();
                    List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<>();
                    Price price = new Price();
              price.setDate(CurrentDate.getCurrentTimeWithTimeZone());
                    price.setPrice(company.getLTP());
                    prices.add(price);


                    pastPrice.setSymbol(company.getSymbol());
                    pastPrice.setPrices(prices);
                  }   

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: could you show where do you actually try to save the price?

Answer (score 0):

Below should work:

1. Move List prices out of company Loop
2. save pastPrice  after loop.

   @GetMapping("/save")
   public void getAndSaveStocks() {

   ```
   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   StockData stockData = restTemplate.getForObject(Constants.API,
           StockData.class);
   List<Company> sl = stockData.getCompanies();

   PastPrice pastPrice = new PastPrice();
   List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<>();
   for (Company company : sl) {
       Price price = new Price();
       price.setDate(CurrentDate.getCurrentTimeWithTimeZone());
       price.setPrice(company.getLTP());
       prices.add(price);

   }

   pastPrice.setSymbol(company.getSymbol());
   pastPrice.setPrices(prices);
   ```

   }